# Metabox context for page post type

Tags: metabox

I would like to add a meta box underneath the title, but before the editor on a page post type in admin. I can add it to a post, but not to a page and I don't understand why.

I've used this to add a new context that will appear under the title.

```
function buddydev_create_new_metboax_context( $post ) {

do_meta_boxes( null, 'custom-metabox-holder', $post );
}
add_action( 'edit_form_after_title', 'buddydev_create_new_metboax_context'  );
```

This works fab on a post, but if I try to add it to the page post type the metabox displays beneath the text editor, not above it.

Here is my metabox code.

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'at_titles_meta_box' );

function at_titles_meta_box($post){
add_meta_box('at_meta_box', 'Add Title', 'titles_meta_box', array('page'), 'custom-metabox-holder');
}

add_action('save_post', 'at_save_metabox');

function at_save_metabox(){ 
global $post;
if(isset($_POST["tagline"])){
    //UPDATE: 
    $tagline = $_POST['tagline'];
    $sub = $_POST['sub'];

    //END OF UPDATE
    update_post_meta($post->ID, 'tagline', $tagline);
    update_post_meta($post->ID, 'sub', $sub);   
}
}

function titles_meta_box($post){
$tagline = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'tagline', true); 
$sub = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'sub', true);

?>   

<p>
<label for="tagline">Banner Strapline:</label>

<input class="widefat" type="text" name="tagline" id="tagline" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'tagline', true ) ); ?>" size="30" />
<br /><br />
<label for="sub">Intro Section Title:</label>

<input class="widefat" type="text" name="sub" id="sub" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'sub', true ) ); ?>" size="30" />
</p>

<?php
}
```

Comment: You _could_ just add your metabox content into that filter and test against `get_current_screen()` to ensure your on the correct post type.

Comment: I don't think you understand what I mean. The metabox does appear on the page post type, but in the wrong place. I've tried using the get_current_screen(), but it didn't make a difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is user settings (user metadata) which override the initial meta box order. So it is up to user which meta box he want to display first. User can drag and drop metaboxes and arrange them in any order which he want regardless the order you've defined.

You can go to user meta table and find key with name `meta-box-order_{post_type}` e.g. `meta-box-order_page` delete the value of this key then check again.

There is nothing wrong with your code.